# How to add a circle on the top right corner of a div and show ellipsis with text overflow

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to show a list of the dynamically added item after appends in a div with jquery. I want the max-width of the div as 400px only. and it should ellipsis with text-overflow: hidden. There will be a badge over the top-right corner of the div.

But using the `text-overflow: hidden`, the circle is also hidden.

Currently i am getting:

[image]

But correctly it should display as:

[image]

```js
function buttonClick() {
  var inputValue = $("#inputField").val();

  $(".fileContent").append(
    '<div id="fileList" class="fileName-label">' +
    inputValue +
    '  <div class="badge"><a href="#"  class="close">X</a></div></div>'
  );

  $("#inputField").val(" ");
}
```

```css
.fileName-label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  padding: .50rem 0.40rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.fileContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* position: absolute; */
}

.fileContent #fileList {
  margin-top: 0.70rem;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.badge {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #FF4081;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.badge :hover {
  background-color: #fc1463;
}

.close {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="inputField" />
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="buttonClick();return false;" />

<div class="fileContent">
</div>
```

Comment: Why not put a span for the input value and add text-overflow: hidden to it?

Comment: and what about the ellipsis?

Comment: I meant adding this to the span `text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;` instead of the div

Comment: @GowthamRajJ your solution is not working, have you tried by checking yourself first?

Comment: Does the answer from BOZ work for you?

Comment: @AakashBashyal My bad for suggesting to wrap it using span, text-overflow works on block element, need to wrap it in a div instead of span or add a display: block with those two css property. And BOZ has added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to make the two properties on the same element, just edit the text element separately and its wrapper is free.

```js
function buttonClick() {

  var inputValue = $("#inputField").val();

  $('.fileContent').append('<div id="fileList" class="fileName-label"><div class="text">' + inputValue + '  </div><div class="badge"><a href="#"  class="close">X</a></div></div>');

  $("#inputField").val(" ")

}
```

```css
.fileName-label {
  position: relative;
}

.fileName-label .text {
  padding: .50rem 0.40rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  margin-top: 0.70rem;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.fileContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* position: absolute; */
}

.badge {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #FF4081;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.badge :hover {
  background-color: #fc1463;
}

.close {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="inputField" value="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book." />
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="buttonClick();return false;" />

<div class="fileContent">
</div>
```